# How can I use a 2009 iMac as an external monitor for a 2019 MacBook Air?

Tags: external-display, thunderbolt, mini-displayport

I tried to use a Thunderbolt cable and a Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 adaptor for this process but it was unsuccessful. My research led me to figure out that my 2009 27" iMac has a mini display port NOT a thunderbolt port making them incompatible.

Am I correct in assuming that I will need a cable that is mini display port to mini display port? If this is the case how do I connect the mini display to my laptop? Will I need another adaptor that is mini display to USB-3 because the thunderbolt 2 to thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) will not work? Does such an adapter exist?

The mini display port to mini display port cable seems uncommon though I was able to find one on amazon. Also I have noticed that there is female and male mini display ports, what is the difference?

Thank you for your help!